# {name: "Name", value: 1} is invalid JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a string below which I am trying to convert into a JSON object and am using the syntax `var json = JSON.parse(myjson);` but it is saying expected token } but I can't see where?

Does anyone know where this would be?

```
[{name:"After", value:1},{name:"watching", value:1},{name:"you", value:1},{name:"at", value:3},{name:"Birmngm", value:1},{name:"my", value:1},{name:"new", value:2},{name:"athlete", value:1},{name:"to", value:1},{name:"follow.", value:1},{name:"Love", value:2},{name:"the", value:4},{name:"passion,", value:1},{name:"enthusiasm", value:1},{name:"and", value:3},{name:"big", value:1},{name:"smiles!!", value:1},{name:"Long", value:1},{name:"may", value:1}]
```

Comment: this is a good tool for that: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: No, it is not. The property names miss string delimiters.

Comment: Show us the code please. Did you mistook a simple object literal for JSON?

Comment: @pst: Don't forget about http://timelessrepo.com/json-isnt-a-javascript-subset

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is totally invalid JSON. Every key MUST be quoted. e.g.

```
[{"name":"After","value":1}, ....
  ^--  ^--       ^--   ^--
```

Comment: Thank you :) I didn't realise

Comment: don't generate json strings by yourself. it's too painful/unreliable. use your host language's json interfaces, e.g. php's `json_encode()`.

Comment: @MarcB: But code the PHP associative arrays by hand? At some point, data needs to be inserted into the system, and JSON (if properly indented) is a quite simple format.

Comment: @bergi: json is a simple format, but when you're dealing with nested data structures, it gets to be a serious pain. far easier to deal with your platforms **NATIVE** types and then have it translate to json for you. this is especially true if you're building that nested json structure iteratively.

Answer (score 1):

It is not valid json.  You'll need to put quotes around your keys like this

```
{
    "name": "After",
    "value": 1
},
```

[JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) is a great tool for debugging JSON issues, it can tell you whether a specific string is valid and point you to where a problem is.

Answer (score 1):

This is valid JavaScript, not valid JSON.  You can open chromes developer console, and stringify this to get valid JSON:

```
[{"name":"After","value":1},{"name":"watching","value":1},{"name":"you","value":1},{"name":"at","value":3},{"name":"Birmngm","value":1},{"name":"my","value":1},{"name":"new","value":2},{"name":"athlete","value":1},{"name":"to","value":1},{"name":"follow.","value":1},{"name":"Love","value":2},{"name":"the","value":4},{"name":"passion,","value":1},{"name":"enthusiasm","value":1},{"name":"and","value":3},{"name":"big","value":1},{"name":"smiles!!","value":1},{"name":"Long","value":1},{"name":"may","value":1}]
```

Answer (score 1):

The provided string is correct if you try to build a JS object. However in order to create a valid JSON string you need to surround the keys in quotes. hence you should encapsulate `name` and `value` in double or single quotes. you can use [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com) to validate.